# How to extract unique nested variable names out of one string variable?

Tags: mysql, json

**Case**

In our MySql database the data is stored in combined json-strings like this:

```
| ID | DATA |

| 100  | {var1str: "sometxt", var2double: 0,01, var3integer: 1, var4str: "another text"} |
| 101  | {var3integer: 5, var2double: 2,05, var1str: "txt", var4str: "more text"} |
```

**Problem**

Most of the DATA-fields hold over 2500 variables. The order of variables in the DATA-string is random (as shown in above example). Right now we only know how to extract data with the following querie:

```
select   
ID, 
json_extract(DATA,'var1str'),
json_extract(DATA,'var2double'),
FROM table
```

With this querie, only the values of var1str and var2double will be returned as result. Values of variable 3 and 4 are ignored. **There is no overview of what possible variables are hiding in the data fields.**

With almost 60.000 entries and over 3.000 possible unique variable names, I would like to create a query that loops through all of the 60.000 DATA-fields and extracts every unique variable name that is found in there.

**Solution?**

The querie I am looking for would give the following result:

```
var1str
var2double
var3integer
var4str
```

My knowledge of MySql is very limited. Any direction given to get to this solution is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there is a single query that can do that for you; a stored procedure could, but in that case you might be better off just parsing the data in your client-side language.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I looked a bit into stored procedures, I think this is possible in HeidiSQL. Would using that be the same thing as  what you call 'parsing data in client-side language'?

Comment: Yes, a stored procedure should be capable, but client-side languages tend to have better libraries (such as standard "split string" methods) to facilitate these kinds of things.

Answer (score 1):

What version of MySQL are you using?.

From MySQL 8.0.4 and later [JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table) function is supported and can be useful in this case.

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.11    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` (
    ->   `ID` BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   `DATA` JSON NOT NULL
    -> ) AUTO_INCREMENT=100;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `table`
    ->   (`DATA`)
    -> VALUES
    ->   ('{"var1str": "sometxt", "var2double": 0.01, "var3integer": 1, "var4str": "another text"}'),
    ->   ('{"var3integer": 5, "var2double": 2.05, "var1str": "txt", "var4str": "more text"}');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT
    ->   DISTINCT `der`.`key`
    -> FROM
    ->   `table`,
    ->   JSON_TABLE(
    ->     JSON_KEYS(`DATA`), '$[*]'
    ->     COLUMNS(
    ->       `key` VARCHAR(64) PATH "$"
    ->     )
    ->   ) `der`;
+-------------+
| key         |
+-------------+
| var1str     |
| var4str     |
| var2double  |
| var3integer |
+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Be aware of the [Bug #90610 ERROR 1142 (42000) when using JSON_TABLE](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90610).